# PHP cannot take HTML post form variables after submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a "Sign Up" form inside a modal and a script like this:

```js
$(function () {

  $("#lala").on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'signup.php',
      data: $("#lala").serialize(),
      success: function () {
        alert('form was submitted');
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    ×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Log In</h4></a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-right: 30px;">
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li><a href="#Registration" data-toggle="tab">Sign Up</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="Registration">
                                <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" style="padding-top: 20px;" method="post" id="lala">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                            Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="honorific">
                                                        <option>Mr.</option>
                                                        <option>Ms.</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="fullname" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                            Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                            Password</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="typeOfParticipant"  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sign up as</label>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                <select class="form-control" onChange="option1(this.value)" name="persona">
                                                    <option value=""></option>
                                                    <option value="participant">Participant</option>
                                                    <option value="researcher">Researcher</option>
                                                    <option value="exhibitor">Exhibitor</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="op1" style="margin-left: 11px;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="submit">
                                                Submit</button>
                                            <button type="reset" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                                Cancel</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My "signup.php" looks like this:

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "eam";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$email = $_POST["email"];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
$honorific = $_POST['honorific'];
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$persona = $_POST['persona'];

$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM registered";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    $id = 1;
}
else{
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $id = $row['maxid']+1;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO registered (id, email, password, honorific, fullname, persona)
VALUES ({$id}, {$email}, {$pwd}, {$honorific}, {$fullname}, {$persona})";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The problem is that, no matter what I have tried, the form variables just will not pass in signup.php. I have checked them and yes, they are empty. Is there any way you can help me figure out why?

Comment: a good way of testing this will be by simply doing echo $email in the server side. Also you don't need to share all of your sql queries in your PHP.

Comment: How are you checking? Troubleshooting done so far is not very clear

Comment: I've printed the variables for error checking and they are empty. SQL works fine, I've checked it manually. The only problem is that the variables that are supposed to get a value from the post form are empty.

Comment: Are you saying if you do `var_dump($_POST)`, it is empty?

Comment: @BizzyBob Yes, it's empty

Comment: I wonder if it just looks like it's empty since you are using AJAX.  When you post the form normally, you would see the var_dump at the top of the page.  But when you use AJAX, the page does't refresh, so you won't see it.  Try posting the form 'normally' by commenting out your JS code.  Then, once it's working as expected, change it back to using AJAX via JS.